# Escaping scriptlet output in Grails 2.3.0

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following in a GSP:

```
<%=model.something%>
```

And in Config.groovy, I have:

```
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
            codecs {
                expression = 'html' // escapes values inside null
                scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                taglib = 'html' // escapes output from taglibs
                staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
            }
        }
        // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
        filteringCodecForContentType {
            //'text/html' = 'html'
        }
    }
}
```

But when I set model.something = "<script>alert('something')</script>" in the controller and render the view, I get the alert box.

If I change it to use ${model.something} instead, it appears to escape properly. But I'd like to be on the safe side and ensure that scriptlet output is also encoded. Do I need something else in the config to make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `<%=%>` form does not imply any escaping. Just use `${}`.

> Variables within the ${..} block are not escaped by default, so any HTML in the variable's string is rendered directly to the page. To reduce the risk of Cross-site-scripting (XSS) attacks, you can enable automatic HTML escaping with the grails.views.default.codec setting.

Note, there is nothing said about `<%=%>`. As by my own practice I confirm that setting does not affect the JSP tag (you may need to render some things unescaped).